# Google Spreadsheet, Query Date older than 5 years ago

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am trying to query a count of machines that are older than 5 years.

My machine data is in one tab with date time stamps in column K like "8/8/2008 8:08:08"

I have tried many different variations to get the query right... but my latest is like this

```
=query(RawDataMachines!B:K,"select count(K) WHERE K + INTERVAL 5 YEAR < NOW() label count(A1''")
```

Been trying to solve this issue for several days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe HAVING instead of WHERE?

Answer (score 1):

well try this and let me know....

```
select COUNT(K) from Machine where datediff(YEAR,k,getdate()) > 5;
```

datediff will return the number of years between the date k and the System Date.
Hope it Help's.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work... think it is an issue with google docs query not liking some of sql know commands.